# PyTorch: Sharing a model between threads, do I need to lock it myself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I'm sharing a PyTorch neural network model between a main thread which `trains` the model and a number of worker threads which `eval` the model to generate training samples (à la AlphaGo).

My question is, do I need to create a separate mutex to lock and unlock when accessing the model in different threads?

---

I did not see any mutex in the PyTorch [Hogwild](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist_hogwild/main.py) example, however the difference there is that all threads are in `train` mode.

Apart from the official [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html), I'm unable to find even basic information (like this question) online.

I'm using the `torch.multiprocessing` module for this and I'm using `model.share_memory()` and `torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)`.

Comment: Hello! I've met with a similar problem. Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You need to `.join()` all worker threads if you wish to continue using main thread.

Comment: No, when the function ends the other workers get automatically cleaned up, `.join()` just waits for them